# Difference between "enterar por" and "enterar de"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Please read the following sentences:

> Nos enteramos por las noticias que las flores valían más caras que los años anteriores.
>   Al comenzar este invierno me enteré **de** la noticia **de** que haría/iba a hacer mucho frío.

Questions:

1. Are there any differences between "enterar por" and "enterar de"?
2. Why should we need "de" in "la noticia de que haría/iba a hacer mucho frío"? Can we omit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct construction is always :

> Nos enteramos de [algo / something ]

If the "something" is a phrase constructed with a verb, then it's preceeded with "que"; and in this last case, the "de" is sometimes omitted.

Examples:

> Nos enteramos de la noticia.
>
> Nos enteramos de la muerte de Juan.
>
> Nos enteramos de que Juan murió.  (slightly less correct: Nos enteramos que Juan murió)

Regarding the examples in the original question:

In the first phrase "por las noticias" is just a complementary expression, ("por medio de las noticias", "a través de las noticias" = "via the news", "by means of the news"), it is not gramatically attached to the verb, it could be put inside commas, or parentheses:

> Nos enteramos, por las noticias, que las flores valían más caras que los
> años anteriores.

or even removed:

> Nos enteramos (...) que las flores valían más caras que los años anteriores.

By the way: this reveals that the construction is slightly incorrect (though acceptable), it should be better "nos enteramos ... de que..."

The second phrase it's equivalent to:

> Nos enteramos de la siguiente noticia: iba a hacer mucho frío.
>
> Nos enteramos de lo siguiente: iba a hacer mucho frío.
>
> Nos enteramos de que iba a hacer mucho frío.

The expression "la noticia" is slightly redundant here, it just emphasizes that the information was news for us.

EDITED: Regarding the added question:

> me enteré de la noticia de que iba a ...
>
> me enteré de la noticia que iba a ...

The first sentence is the correct one, although it doesn't sound very nice. The omission of *"de"* in the second sentece is incorrect, but it's a minor error: in common speak both forms are accepted. A nicer alternative is: *"me enteré de la noticia: iba a"*.

Some reading material:

http://www.lapatria.com/story/salvataje-miedo-al-deque%C3%ADsmo-has-haz-barista

http://www.udistrital.edu.co/wpmu/flrodriguezh/files/2011/12/Padece-usted-de-dequefobia.pdf

Comment: @leonboy: Thanks for your detailed answer. I've edited my question again. In the second sentence, there are two "de", can I omit the second one? If not, why should we need it?

Answer (score 0):

1.- "Me enteré por X de Y" means "I learnt through X that Y is the case".

2.- You can't omit "de" in "la noticia de que iba a hacer frío".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited my question again. In the second sentence, there are two "de", can I omit the second one? If not, why should we need it?

Comment: That's what I meant: you can't omit the "de" in "la noticia de que iba a hacer frío". More examples: "la razón de que vengas", "la excusa de que ibas a llegar tarde", "la importancia de que nos lo digas"... You see, it's a standard pattern in Spanish. :)